# How to resolve this : Expected a string, Doc, or bytes as input, but got: <class 'float'>

Tags: python, nlp

My main objective was to remove stop words and puntuations from a large amount of text within the dataset. However after 5 minutes of the code running i got this error.

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-121-c761affbd958> in <cell line: 2>()
      1 # Apply preprocess funtion to text data in dataset
----> 2 df_balanced['Preprocessed_text'] = df_balanced['text'].apply(tf_preprocess)

6 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/spacy/language.py in _ensure_doc(self, doc_like)
   1122         if isinstance(doc_like, bytes):
   1123             return Doc(self.vocab).from_bytes(doc_like)
-> 1124         raise ValueError(Errors.E1041.format(type=type(doc_like)))
   1125 
   1126     def _ensure_doc_with_context(

ValueError: [E1041] Expected a string, Doc, or bytes as input, but got: <class 'float'>
```

My preprocessing code is as follows:

```
# Further Preprocessing
# remove stopwords and puntuations
tf_nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")
def tf_preprocess(text):
  doc_15 = tf_nlp(text)
  filtered_data = []
  for token in doc_15:
    if token.is_stop or token.is_punct:
      continue
    filtered_data.append(token.lemma_)
  return " ".join(filtered_data)
```

I would like to know how to resolve that error.
Thank you for your time and suggestions :)

Comment: Looks like whatever you're passing to `tf_preprocess()` as `text` is a `float` instead of something it can handle. Where/how are you calling `tf_preprocess()`?

Comment: As i said its an enormous amount of text data. Is there a way to access the floats present in the data and remove them?

Comment: you might hack it with `doc_15 = tf_nlp(str(text))`